# What is the meaning of 現箱さき親方?

Tags: meaning

```
本名ジョー•力石、現箱さき親方
```

現 is reality/consciousness or present/current, 箱 is box/shamisen, 親方 is master/craftsman. And さき is 先? So 現箱さき親方 is "top shamisen craftsman of the present day"?

Comment: Pure guesswork, yeah?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think 箱さき is his name as a sumo stable master. 現 means 現在の, which means "present". Probably this 親方 means "a sumo stable master". So it means "The present Hakosaki sumo stable master".

You may wonder why the word "present" is necessary. It is because sumo stable masters take on the names of their masters. Thus there must be a way to distinguish between the present and past masters.

Comment: Thank you, I'd never have thought 箱さき is a name. Does it mean something?

Comment: It is a last name and also name of places.

Comment: Are you sure "hereditary" is the right word?

Comment: I misunderstood 世襲 as 襲名. Thank you for teaching.

Comment: "Succeed" does not work that way. Edited a bit. Hope it's an improvement.